# Do not load certain images when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, onload

I have a webpage, a simple index.php. With jquery I managed to set up 5 individual menus. Unfortunately I have to use like 150 thumbnail images in my gallery, and whenever I reload the page, all those pictures need to load in as well and it takes like 5-6 seconds. I tried to set up Lazy Load jquery addon, but it just didn't work for me (it is written for scrolling websites I guess..and mine is not like that).

I was thinking about writing a script, which prevents all those images loadin, but I don't even know how to start. My point is, thumbnail images should be loading only if the user clicks on the gallery link (which is the very same php page though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the images' url in a separate attribute like:

```
<img data-realsrc='realsrc'>
```

and then when you need to load them:

```
$(img).attr('src', $(img).data('realsrc'));
```

The above is the general implementation principle. For a real example look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3UrUZ/

BTW doing what you did is not a good practice. I suggest you to use [CSS Sprites](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/11/css-sprites-revisited/) istead of a lot of images. :) And there are a lot of sprites generators to help creating them.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but now I get black images instead of the real thumbnails. I'm using data-realsrc="..." instead of the src inside the img tag.

Comment: please post some code, like the html and js code :)

Comment: <script>
    $(img).attr('src', $(img).data('realsrc'));
    </script>

This goes right after <body>.

And this is my gallery.

<?php
foreach($image as $img)
  {
   if($img== reset($image))
   {
<div class=\"thumbnail\"><img src=\"\" data-realsrc=\"images/etc/thumbs/".$img.".jpg\" /></div>
}
}
?>

Comment: yeah. i've just added a full example. I wrote the general coding principle here.